# Stop Paragraph from Passing A Certain Point in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently, I am working on a website which includes JavaScript Animations . The image in the first part of the page should be responsive, which currently works as intended, but I want to keep the paragraph of the next section to stay in a certain place/not pass a certain place.

I have tried to use the overflow function in CSS, but it lets the text of the paragraph to pass the point.

[image]

The above image shows the paragraph text. I do not want it to pass into the black. How would I go about doing this (new to html,css and js). Note the JavaScript is using TweenMax.

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/AshS123/w0k8mjys/2/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Homepage</title>
    </head>
<body>
    
        
    <header>
        <nav>
            
         
        </nav>
        <div id="container">
            
         
        <section>
            <div class="backgroundimage">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1483651842966-0a111943c528?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" alt="background">
                <h1 class="headline">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
            </div>
         </section>

        </header>
        
        <div class="slider"></div>
        <div class="about">
            <h2 class="aboutme"> ABOUT</h2>
            <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
        </div>
        
        
         </div>
        
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Wy4KH0O+AuzjMm1w5QfZ5j5/y8Q/kcUktK9mPUVaUoBvh3QPUZB822W/vy7ULqri3yR8daH3F58+Y8Z08qzeg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TimelineMax.min.js" integrity="sha512-lJDBw/vKlGO8aIZB8/6CY4lV+EMAL3qzViHid6wXjH/uDrqUl+uvfCROHXAEL0T/bgdAQHSuE68vRlcFHUdrUw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    
    </body>




</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
   
    
}

.slider{
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background:black;
    z-index: -1;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 350px;
    min-height: 900px;    
    }

nav {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 10% 1fr 1fr 10%;
    min-height: 10vh;
    color: white;
    max-width: 100vw;
    
}
#Logo{
grid-column: 2/3;
    font-size: 14px;
}


section {
    display: flex;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-height: 80vh;
    max-width: 80vw;
    min-height: 75vh;
    min-width: 75vw;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
     
}
.backgroundimage {
    height: 80%;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    min-width: 200px;
    
}  
.backgroundimage img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    min-width: 200px;

    
    
}
.headline {
    position:absolute;
    top: 80%;
    left:10%;
    font-size: 7vw;
    transform: translate(-20%, -70%);
    color: pink;
    z-index:5;
    
    

}
.backgroundimage::after{
    content: "";
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.6;
    top: 0;
}

#container {
    max-height: 95vh;
    max-width: 100%;
    
    
    }
.about.lead{
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 13rem;
    padding-left: 11rem;
    padding-left: 10vw;
    padding-right: 10vw;
    z-index: -2;

}
p.lead {
    font-family: "Lora", serif;
    font-size:calc(10px + 1.2vw);
    line-height: 1.8;
    color: #888888;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 25vw;
   margin-right: 25vw;
  
   overflow:hidden;
   z-index: -2;
   

   
}
.about {
    height: 100%;
    
    margin-top: 30vh;
    max-height: 80vh;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: auto;
    height: 500px;
    z-index: -10;

}

h2 {
    font-family: "Lora", serif; 
    text-decoration: bold;
    color: rgb(255, 42, 95);
    margin-right: -30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
.lead {
    min-height: 150px;
    font-size: min(1em, 12px);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
const backgroundimage = document.querySelector(".backgroundimage");
const slider = document.querySelector(".slider");
const headline = document.querySelector(".headline");

const tl = new TimelineMax();

tl.fromTo
(backgroundimage, 
0.8, {height: "0%"},
{ height: "80%", ease: Power2.easeInOut})

.fromTo
(backgroundimage,
0.8, {width: '100%'}, {width: '80%', ease: Power2.easeInOut})

.fromTo(
    slider,
    0.8,
    { x: "-100%" },
    { x: "0%", ease:Power2.easeInOut },
    "=0.8"
);
```

Comment: Do you want your text to be cut/stopped after some point? Could you explain why is the overflow feature not doing that for you?

Comment: I want the paragraph's text to stop moving upwards past the black background. I tried the overflow feature and currently the issue is the div which overlaps with the black background.

Comment: to me it looks like the Black background slider is moving not the text. And thats most likely caused by the "position: absolute" in the Slider

Comment: Changing the position to absolute fixed the movement issue, but now the black background slider is no longer behind the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the `min-height: 900px` rule from the `.slider` element, since on smaller heights it forces the height of the slider (which is the black background) to be bigger that the height of the header container, so it overlaps with the paragraph below.

Comment: This keeps the paragraph inside the white section, but this also allows the paragraph from moving underneath the image.Is there a fix to stop the paragraph and section moving under the image.

Comment: You should remove `max-height` and `min-height` and add `height: 100vh` to the `section` element. That way, everything will be contained in the black section and the paragraph will be beneath it.

Comment: here is the fiddle with that changes: https://jsfiddle.net/sgv28y61/